# Ruby Array Issue - can't convert String into Integer

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

Can't understand what the issue with this

```
nameTag = "div[class='designer_about'] a"
designsTag = "li[class='span-2']"
pullTags = Array.new(nameTag, designsTag)
```

Error:

```
designers_list_mirraw.rb:8:in `initialize': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
from designers_list_mirraw.rb:8:in `new'
from designers_list_mirraw.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

I am new to ruby

Comment: Don't use `Array.new`. Use the `['array', 'literal']`. Could this be the cause?

Comment: @JanDvorak thanks. It helped. But I saw the above method outhere http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_arrays.htm

Comment: If your question has been answered you should accept the one you found most helpful.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As juanpastas mentions, [`Array::new(size,obj)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-c-new) expects a number and an object. You can see this in the tutorial you linked to:

```
names = Array.new(4, "mac")
```

`names` is now an array with `"mac"` four times.

If your intention is to create an array with these two items:

```
pullTags = Array.[nameTag, designsTag]
# which is equivalent to
pullTags = Array[nameTag, designsTag]
# which are the more verbose versions of
pullTags = [nameTag, designsTag]
```

See [[](*args)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D).

Answer (score 4):

`Ary.new(length, item)` is for the time you need an array have same item duplicate for certain times. It's not `Array.new(item, item)`. The first parameter represent the length of array you want.

In your case you should use:

```
name_tag = "div[class='designer_about'] a"
designs_tag = "li[class='span-2']"
pull_tags = [name_tag, designs_tag]
```

BTW, by Ruby's convention, `snake_case_variable_name` is more preferred then `camelCaseVariabelName`

Answer (score 3):

See [Array::new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-c-new)

It receives integer and then an object, or an Array too, so you could use:

```
Array.new(2,'some') => ['some','some']
Array.new(an_array_here)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ways to Build Arrays

The confusion comes from the fact that there are many ways to build arrays in Ruby. A non-exhaustive list includes:

1. Calling [Kernel#Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array).
2. Calling [Array#new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-c-new).
3. Construct an [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html) with an array literal, e.g. `[]`.

The semantics of each vary. The way you're doing it has the following signature:

> Array#new(size=0, obj=nil)

which means the first argument is the size of the array, not an array element itself. Use a different invocation to achieve your desired results.

Answer (score 1):

see the  [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html)

```
nameTag = "div[class='designer_about'] a"
designsTag = "li[class='span-2']"
```

The new method can be called in this ways:

```
Array.new # => []
Array.new(2) # => [nil,nil]
Array.new(2,designsTag) # =>["li[class='span-2']", "li[class='span-2']"]
```

Or to add elements one by one you can use the push method:

```
[ 1, 2 ] << "c" << "d" << [ 3, 4 ] #=> [ 1, 2, "c", "d", [ 3, 4 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have string items, you can also use `%W`

```
> nameTag = "div[class='designer_about'] a"
# => "div[class='designer_about'] a" 
> designsTag = "li[class='span-2']"
# => "li[class='span-2']"
> %W(#{nameTag} #{designsTag}) 
# => ["div[class='designer_about'] a", "li[class='span-2']"]
```

**Reference** : http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#arrays